# xsl:attribute with condition and handlebars

Tags: javascript, xslt, handlebars.js

I try to set xsl:attribute with handlebars.
The code is:

```
<input type="text">
  {{#if_eq line_type 0}}
    <xsl:attribute name="disabled">true</xsl:attribute>
  {{/if_eq}}
</input>
```

But such construction doesn't work.
Is there some way to solve the probmlem?

Comment: Can you explain what actuly trying to get ?

Comment: I hava a input field. From server I receive a data (for example: var myData = {line_type: 1}). Depending on the line_type value I want to set disable attrbute for the input field.

Comment: so what it displayed? blank or some thing else? is #if_eq condition  true ? please give more details so you can get easily solution.

Comment: Attribute doesn't set. Never.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to add something like following:

JavaScript:

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('equal', function(lvalue, rvalue, options) {
        if (arguments.length < 3)
            throw new Error("Handlebars Helper equal needs 2 parameters");

        if( lvalue!=rvalue ) {
            return options.inverse(this);
        } else {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
    });
```

In HTML template like:

```
<input type="text">
  {{#equal line_type 0}}
    <xsl:attribute name="disabled">true</xsl:attribute>
  {{/equal}}
</input>
```

hope it will help.

edited:

```
{{#equal line_type 0}}    
<input type="text">
        <xsl:attribute name="disabled">true</xsl:attribute>

    </input>
{{/equal}}
```

Comment: Don't work.The problem not in helper. I think, that I need some magicaly escape  {{#if}} block to process xsl attribute correctly.

Comment: so you can use directly : <xsl:if line_type=0>
  ...some output if the expression is true...
</xsl:if> without using handelbarjs

Comment: line_type in a other scope. It is a property of javascript object;

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But I think, there must be a more elegant solution to the problem :)